# Pandas - Filter Col with Object DType for a Couple Conditions

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column in a df with object dtype. I'm having some trouble filtering for just the ones with $xxxxxxx and CAD in the price field.

```
Price
$1,000,000
$2,000,000
$700,000
1,234,567 CAD
$111,111
3,000,000 EUR
Inquire
$500,000
Auction
```

I have tried this without success:

```
df = df[(df['Price'].str.contains('$')) | (df['Price'].str.contains('CAD'))]
```

If I want just the CAD, this works:

```
df = df[df['Price'].str.contains('CAD')
```

But, how do I get all values with just a $ and CAD? So remove 3 in my sample data above (EUR, Inquire, Auction).

Comment: I've tried a few other things like replacing the $ with USD, and then filtering for USD and CAD like above, but that didn't work. I also tried a couple of other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `\` for escape character and `|` for or operations. [pd.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=contains#pandas-series-str-contains) where the pattern is default to use regex:

```
df[df['Price'].str.contains('\$|CAD')]
```

Output:

```
           Price
0     $1,000,000
1     $2,000,000
2       $700,000
3  1,234,567 CAD
4       $111,111
7       $500,000
```

And, if you also wanted to catch that 'EUR', use another `|`:

```
df[df['Price'].str.contains('\$|CAD|EUR')]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked just adding one simple character!

Answer (score 2):

`$` is a special character in regex, and [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) enables regex by default. You can disable regex, use `re.escape`, or escape via `\`:

```
import re

# choose one of the below    
m1 = df['Price'].str.contains('$', regex=False)  # disable regex, most efficient
m1 = df['Price'].str.contains(re.escape('$'))    # escape via re.escape
m1 = df['Price'].str.contains('\$')              # escape via \

# turn off regex when not required for a performance boost
m2 = df['Price'].str.contains('CAD', regex=False)

print(df[m1 | m2])

           Price
0     $1,000,000
1     $2,000,000
2       $700,000
3  1,234,567 CAD
4       $111,111
7       $500,000
```

Most adaptable is to use regex with `re.escape`. For example:

```
L = ['$', 'CAD']
search_str = '|'.join(map(re.escape, L))
df = df[df['Price'].str.contains(search_str)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks interesting. I will try it out and need to add stuff like this to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I see already we have answers by experts but just another approach for posterity sake.

```
>>> df[ df['Price'].str.startswith('$') | df['Price'].str.endswith('CAD') ]
           Price
0     $1,000,000
1     $2,000,000
2       $700,000
3  1,234,567 CAD
4       $111,111
7       $500,000
```